# bxSlider, content slides in on document ready

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bxslider

I am using the bxSlider (http://bxslider.com/) to display content in carousel-sort of way. Now my art director wants me to make sure that the visitors understand that there is more content to be had if the pager-icons are clicked. To indicate this, he wants the first slide to slide in from the right, when content has finished loading.

I tried to achieve this using jquery's: show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000); on the containing ul. But the sliding effect isn't achieved. Instead, it just plainly pops into view.

Anyone who knows why this behaves this way or know another way to achieve this?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function () {

        var slides = $("#eventslider>li");

        if (slides.length < 4) {
            $('#next-button').hide();
        }

        var slider = $('#eventslider').bxSlider({
            controls: false,
            mode: 'horizontal',
            displaySlideQty: 3,
            moveSlideQty: 3,
            infiniteLoop: false,
            hideControlOnEnd: true
        });

        setTimeout("showSlider()", 1000);


    });

    function showSlider() {
        $("#eventslider").show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 1000);
    }
</script> 

<ul id="eventslider" style="display:none">

    <li>
        <p class="date">
            2011-12-31</p>

        <h3><a href="http://domain/en-gb/events_training/Pages/Event-wo-Image.aspx">
            Event wo Image</a></h3>
        <p class="rollUp">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet</p>

        <p>
            <a href="http://domain/en-gb/events_training/Pages/Event-wo-Image.aspx">
                Read more
            </a>
        </p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p class="date">
            2011-12-16</p>
        <div class="imagecontainer"><a href="http://domain/se/events_training/Pages/Lokal-händelse-sverigeen-GB.aspx"><img src="/SiteCollectionImages/industries/top/yellowcoats.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>            
        <h3><a href="http://domain/se/events_training/Pages/Lokal-händelse-sverigeen-GB.aspx">
            Local event sweden</a></h3>
        <p class="rollUp">Vad som helst</p>

        <p>
            <a href="http://domain/se/events_training/Pages/Lokal-händelse-sverigeen-GB.aspx">
                Read more
            </a>
        </p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p class="date">
            2011-12-14</p>

        <h3><a href="http://domain/en-gb/events_training/Pages/Older-event.aspx">
            Older event</a></h3>
        <p class="rollUp">asfasdf</p>

        <p>
            <a href="http://domain/en-gb/events_training/Pages/Older-event.aspx">
                Read more
            </a>
        </p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <p class="date">
            2011-10-19</p>
        <div class="imagecontainer"><a href="http://domain/en-gb/events_training/Pages/Test.aspx"><img src="/SiteCollectionImages/126084-matte-white-square-icon-transport-travel-transportation-airplane1.png" alt="" /></a></div>            
        <h3><a href="http://domain/en-gb/events_training/Pages/Test.aspx">
            Test</a></h3>
        <p class="rollUp">Test again</p>

        <p>
            <a href="http://domain/en-gb/events_training/Pages/Test.aspx">
                Read more
            </a>
        </p>
    </li>

    </ul>
```

Regards,
Rikard

Comment: Never mind, I just wrapped the <ul> in a div which I hid and the applied the slide-effect to and it worked.